# Connect react native to an existing php and mysql project

Tags: php, mysql, react-native

So I currently have a website built with PHP and MySQL that is hosted by a provider similar to GoDaddy (called "XSERVER" or "エックスサーバー").

I've been trying to connect the MySQL server to a react-native project so that I could GET and POST information from my app, but I haven't had any luck.
The hosting company does not allow node.js to be run on their servers, so the option of express.js was eliminated.

what other option could I take to connect a PHP and MySQL server to a react-native app?

Sorry for the general and ambiguous question, I genuinely don't know who to ask or if I should give up.

The website: https://kasumushi.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options to create an API with MySQL and PHP. This API can then be used in your React native application. You should incorporate some sort of auth mechanism to be sure that only your react app can interact with the API.

Either [create one from scratch](https://www.positronx.io/create-simple-php-crud-rest-api-with-mysql-php-pdo/), or use a [REST API framework](https://www.phpflow.com/php/restful-api-frameworks-for-php/)

Comment: You could also look into headless CMS'es, like e.g. [Sanity](https://www.sanity.io/) or [Prismic](https://prismic.io/) or even with the Wordpress [API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)